# How to change cloud function parameters when deploying python gen2?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am writing Firebase Cloud Function in python using the new ["Firebase way"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd).

I would like to be able to set the `region` and memory for the function when i deploy them, in Node JS this is easy :

```
setGlobalOptions({ region: "asia-northeast1" });

exports.date = onRequest({
    // set concurrency value
    concurrency: 500
  },
  (req, res) => {
    // ...
});
```

How to do the same in python :

```
from firebase_functions import https_fn
from firebase_admin import initialize_app

initialize_app()

logging.getLogger("Functions").setLevel(logging.INFO)


@https_fn.on_request()
def example(req: https_fn.CallableRequest) -> https_fn.Response:
    logging.info(f"Request example called : {req.auth}")
    return https_fn.Response("Hello world!")
```

EDIT :

I have found the `set_global_options()` method by playing around and guessing from NodeJS.

However, i still need the answer to set the `options.HttpsOptions` parameters for each function inside `@https_fn.on_call(options=HttpsOptions(something...))`

Comment: Have you seen the API reference? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/python/firebase_functions.options#firebase_functions.options.HttpsOptions

Comment: Care to post that as an answer @DougStevenson? 

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm pretty sure that just a link to documentation does not constitute an acceptable answer!

Comment: Feel free to post an answer to help others with an example in addition to the link : 

from firebase_functions.options import set_global_options, HttpsOptions, MemoryOption, SupportedRegion

`set_global_options(region=SupportedRegion.EUROPE_WEST1, timeout_sec=10, memory=MemoryOption.MB_128)`

And :  `@on_call(HttpsOptions(timeout_sec=20))`

Comment: Sorry, HttpsOptions are not settable inside `@on_call`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters like region, memory, and timeout for Firebase Functions can be set for `on_call()` and `on_request()` functions as `**kwargs`, for details see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/python/firebase_functions.https_fn#functions). Possible parameters and their names are analog to [`HttpsOptions`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/python/firebase_functions.options#httpsoptions).

Example for setting custom values for region, memory, and timeout:

```py
from firebase_functions import https_fn
from firebase_admin import initialize_app

initialize_app()


@https_fn.on_request(region="europe-west3", memory=512, timeout_sec=90)
def example(req: https_fn.CallableRequest) -> https_fn.Response:
    return https_fn.Response("Hello world!")
```